# Generate Web Assembly from CMake Project with a Specified HTML Output

Tags: cmake, emscripten, webassembly

I have a CMake Project that I want to compile to Web assembly. To do so I used the following commands from the base folder of the project:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/ubuntu/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.6/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

This successfully (or at least I think) generates a `.wasm` file and a `.js` file as well as the various cmake and make files .

I also want it to generate an html file, like you can with `emcc` (ie. `emcc example.c -s WASM=1 -o output.html`).

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 12):

You could try and set the `CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX` to `.html` on the command line or the `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: This seems to be used by emscripten tests: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/tests/cmake/target_html/CMakeLists.txt