# How to use emscripten ports (SDL2 and Freetype) with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, port, sdl, emscripten

I'm trying to compile a C++ project using CMake to webassembly. I'm using emscripten and I want to use the emscripten ports for SDL2 and Freetype. Normally, when compiling with emcc, you would use the flags: `-USE_SDL=2` and `-USE_FREETYPE=1`, in order to include these ports. However I don't know how to achieve this using CMake.

This is my CMakeList file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(project src/main.cpp src/glad.c src/Game.cpp src/Block.cpp include/jumpyblock/Block.h)
target_link_libraries(project ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES})
```

It compiles and runs successfully using regular cmake.

So far I have tried compiling with `emcmake cmake . && make`, which gave me an error saying that it couldn't find a package configuration file for SDL2.

And I've tried modifying the CMakeList file to use the emcc flags for the ports:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -USE_SDL=2 -USE_FREETYPE=1")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(project src/main.cpp src/glad.c src/Game.cpp src/Block.cpp include/jumpyblock/Block.h )
target_link_libraries(project ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES})
```

With this cmake file, `emcmake cmake .` runs successfully, but then `make` complains that it can't find `SDL2/SDL.h`.

Comment: Just doing `target_link_libraries(project SDL2 freetype)` should work. In the case with Emscripten freetype and sdl2 will _always_ be there, so there's no need for cross-platform checks.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed the issue based on [this](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/9259) page, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959871/generate-web-assembly-from-cmake-project-with-a-specified-html-output) page, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260216/emscripten-cmake-pass-emscripten-options-in-cmakelist-file) page:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")

if( ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    set(USE_FLAGS "-s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_FREETYPE=1")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX .html)
else()
    find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
    find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
endif()
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(project src/main.cpp src/glad.c src/Game.cpp src/Block.cpp include/jumpyblock/Block.h)
target_link_libraries(project ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES})
```

This compiles with emscripten using `emcmake cmake . && make` and regularly with `cmake . && make`.

Answer (score 5):

I tricked `emcc` into installing zlib port with this:

```
emcc -s USE_ZLIB=1 $(mktemp)
```

and `emcmake cmake ..` started working for me. I bet you should be able  to do the same with SDL.

Comment: I think `embuilder build zlib` is the official way of doing this.